# Letting Users select what image to pull from PHP database to be displayed

Tags: php, mysql

My website consisted of user loaded images being stored in a php database. I am trying to make a page where users can input the "image_id" associated with their image and have it displayed on a page along with some stats(wins/losses). Currently I have to put the image_id in to the code to pull the image.

Here is the code I am using to pull the info from the database

```
<?php
include('mysql.php');

$query="SELECT filename FROM images WHERE image_id = 449";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
$images[] = (object) $row;
}
</php>
```

Here is the code that is displaying the image.

```
<img src="images/<?=$images[0]->filename?>" width="300" />
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax or jquery to take the input, call a php file asynchronously, and load the filename that it sends back. Jquery's $.post is very good for this sort of thing.

Comment: thanks... i'll take a look in to it.. (i'm a little new when it comes to writing scripts)

Comment: If you've never used JQuery they have great tutorials. All you need is a decent understanding of javascript: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Edit: This is more up to date: http://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a dropdown of all available images for user and use the onchange event of dropdown to submit the image_id value back to server, run your query, fetch results and display image...